# I can't get my app into Pre Registration in the Google Play Store

Tags: store, playback

I have an app that I'm going to publicly release next week. Which means my app is ready, testing is over. So I want to start a Pre Registration so people can start pre-downloading the app.

Since the game is ready, I have a production track but is not public because it's controlled with Managed Publishing.

When I go to Pre Registration and Countries tab, I can't add none. It shows that all countries are already in production so I can't add them as Pre Registration, even though my Production Track is not released.

What could I do to start the pre-registration?